# Is there a way to allocate different instances of the same process to different camunda instances(workstations)?

Tags: process, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda, process-management

Is there a way to allocate different instances of the same process to different camunda instances(workstations)?
Since there will be more requests for my camunda process, than my pc can handle, I'm looking for a way to allocate some of those requests to another camunda instance, once mine can't handle any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAMUNDA nodes do not keep state (apart from user session info). In a cluster they synchronize via the database. To distribute the load you can simply start additional environments, which connect to the same database.
Please also see:  https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/introduction/architecture/

You can configure a homogeneous cluster, where all nodes are the same, or a heterogeneous cluster, where the deployment on different nodes differs. Different node types can be deployment-aware (*true*), which means they can be configured to only handle workloads intended for them and for which they have the necessary deployment (classes, libs, etc) and system resources.

Homogeneous Setup
[image: Homogeneous Setup]

Heterogeneous Setup
[image: Heterogeneous Setup]

The job executor is key here. Please see: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/the-job-executor/